# Using jQuery to subtract 1 from a current css value on several divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone know how I would use jQuery to subtract 1 from a current css value of several divs with the same class on a click? I have 5 divs with the same class, each have their own z-index setting. I want to subtract 1 from their current value when I click on one div. My goal is to bring one div forward on click setting z-index to 100. I then want to subtract 1 from the others' current value (whatever that is) on that same click to send them back.

```
$('.classname').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).css("z-index", "100");
    $(this).siblings().css("z-index", - 1);
});
  });
```

This code just sets all the siblings z-index to -1.
Thanks for any help. I'm also open to suggestions on a better way to do this.

Comment: You actually mean the CSS or you mean from a style attribute on the element? Showing your markup would help.

Comment: Sorry, I should of been more clear. I was just talking about changing the style attribute on the element(s).

Answer (score 4):

You can give the `css()` method a function to perform some logic on the current value. Try this:

```
$('.classname').mousedown(function() {
    $(this)
        .css("z-index", "100")
        .siblings().css("z-index", function(i, val) {
            return parseInt(val, 10) - 1;
        });
});
```

Comment: Assuming that the `div`s are `siblings`.`

Comment: @Xotic750 correct, but I've just copied how the OP structured their code.

Comment: Worked like a charm! In my case they are siblings (all divs inside the same parent). I could change the code to effect all divs with the same class? `$('.classname').css("z-index", function(i, val) {`

Answer (score 1):

So basically, you want to do this?

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('classname');

function setZIndex(div) {
  div.style.zIndex = window.getComputedStyle(div).zIndex - 1;
}

function handler(e) {
  [].forEach.call(divs, setZIndex);
  e.target.style.zIndex = 100;
}

[].forEach.call(divs, function(div) {
  div.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
});
```

```css
.classname {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
#one {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
#two {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: -1;
}
#three {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
}
#four {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: -1;
}
#five {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="classname"></div>
<div id="two" class="classname"></div>
<div id="three" class="classname"></div>
<div id="four" class="classname"></div>
<div id="five" class="classname"></div>
```